# how to replace the values in List index C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using `DataGridView` in C# being civil engineer. 
I want the values from a particular row. If the same value appears in a row, I want to display a message. For example, if 1 appears multiple time in a row, i want to display a message on every 1.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1; i++)
    {
        if (CategoryCLO[i] == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Here i am");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I am not");
        }
    }
}

private void dataGridView2_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == 1)
    {
        CategoryCLO.Add(int.Parse(
            dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()));
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
It works right only one time. If a user replaces a value in a cell in `DataGridView`, it adds up another value corresponding to the newly added index of list.

**Explanation:**
The problem is that when user changes value in `DataGridView`, it got adds up in the list, thus increase the index of list , I want that index of list should be fix to the column index. and any change in particular cell , should change in that particular index rather than adding up.

**Question:**
I want that value should be placed in the previous index rather than creating new. In short, I want the indexes of list should be fixed to column number. How can I do it? any direction?

**Note:** Column numbers are variable depending upon the user

Comment: I am sorry but I really doesn't understand what are trying to do here. What represents CategoryCLO (A List(Of Int) I suppose)? In the first event the loop over the DataGridView is useless. Just search with Contains(1) returns true. The second block works only if the edit is on the first row? More explanations are required here

Comment: @Steve yes its a list of int. i want that when same number appears in a row, i want to display a message. for example, if 2 appears in three cells in a row, i want to display a same message using if. The problem is that when user changes value in datagridview, it got adds up in the list, thus increase the index of list , i want that index of list should be fix to the column.

Comment: just save previous value which user changed and in the list find this value and replace with a new one